# Why atomic and nonatomic concept has removed from swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3, atomic, nonatomic

There is no nonatomic keyword in swift, Why nonatomic not required in swift as it exist in objective c.

Answer (score 5):

In Swift the `nonatomic` is the default (and only) choice, so it is not required, unlike Objective-C where `atomic` is the default but often not the desired behaviour.

As for why Swift does not offer `atomic`, well, I guess it has not been seen as a necessary feature by the language designers. Of course you can implement atomic properties with synchronisation, mutexes, semaphores, etc. These solutions are more verbose, but also allow making a truly thread-safe class, unlike just making all properties `atomic` in Objective-C.

Comment: +1 _"but often not the desired behaviour"_ i have seen `atomic NSArray/NSDictionary` code too many times, where it was magically expected to guard the array operations

Comment: And "atomic" doesn't _really_ protect you against race conditions - if two threads set a property at the same time, the fact that they set it won't crash if you use atomic, but you still don't know what is going to happen. Yes, you need @synchronized (or some alternative) plus use of your brain to make code thread safe.